# how to remove a button for a particular cell in tableview in swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am having a tableview in which radio button edit and delete buttons are placed in a particular table view in which the key value pair `default_shipping` is true then the delete button should be hided and edit button needs to move that place and here the user is able to change the default address by clicking edit button and can make another address to be default so that the selected address should have only edit button and the edit button should be placed in position of delete button can anyone help me how to implement this ?

Comment: Check your `indexPath.row` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and hide button for that particular cell.

Comment: but hiding already I tried but my requirement here is edit button should be placed in delete button position for default address if default address changes the same should be applied to all @ivarun

Comment: check if `default_shipping` is true in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and assign `Trailing` constant  of that cell same as delete button's `Trailing` constant.

Comment: if default shipping changes dynamically then how to implement it ? @ivarun

Comment: is it dynamically can change anytime what u said is ?@ivarun

Comment: you need to adjust constraints to move position

Comment: What you're asking really, is how to move a view in a UITableViewCell. The `default_shipping`, and many other details has absolutely no context. Also, it would help to stick a comma somewhere. Try editing your question to focus a little more.

Comment: first, are you able to get `default_shipping `'s indexPath in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: yes I am able to get default_shipping @ivarun

Comment: now simply add condition in `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` for `default_shipping ` if `indexPath.row` == "your default_shipping indexPath.row"' then give edit button Trailing cconstraint's constant same as Delete button's trailing cconstraint's constant. for that you also need to take outlet for edit button's Trailing constraint outlet in `UITableViewCell` class .

Comment: You Can use UIStackView. Just Remove delete button when you need to. Edit button will automatically move to right side.

Comment: @User did you find solution?

Comment: I had taken outlet but it stays in same position it is not changing @ivarun

Comment: but I need to get back dynamically the delete button if user changes the default address  is it possible with ur idea ? @HiteshAgarwal

Comment: here r my constraints for edit button https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RmHs.png @ivarun

Comment: did you change constant of trailing cconstraint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath `?

Comment: changed but the trailing constraint should be given to content view or for delete button ? @ivarun

Comment: given to content view

Comment: working but after scrolling the edit button and delete button is collapsing on a address which is not set as default https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRQ8j.png @ivarun

Comment: did you checked my answer?

Comment: yes it is possible by this idea. You got solution but if you want to try UIStackView than you can ask how to use it :)

Comment: if possible just let me know bro how to implement it @HiteshAgarwal

Comment: Create Horizontal UIStackView and add two buttons in it. On runtime remove button which you like to remove. There are lot's of tutorial on UIStackView on internet. You can check them and get idea on stackview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Give Edit button's Trailing constraint to contentView instead of
  delete button.
- Take outlet of Edit button's Trailing constraint in UITableViewCell's class

Use below code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if indexPath.row == "your default_shipping cell's indexPath.row" {

editButtonTrailing.constant = 8 

} else {

editButtonTrailing.constant = space between delete and edit button.  

}
```